# Pattern Validator for Multiple Consecutive Spaces

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, angular6

My goal is to create an Angular `Validator` to disallow consecutive spaces;

Currently I'm using `Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$')`, which solved the issue. The only problem is, that it also disallows special characters, which I dont want.

- `text   text` shouldn't be valid because there are multiple consecutive spaces
- the validator should also work if the spaces are at the beginning or the end of the string
- `text α` should not throw an error event though `α` is a special character

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Comment: I've added some code

Comment: It does not match text + more than 1 space + text, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hdF4F6/1). What is the actual rule with `α`?

Comment: Do you want to match a string like `"    §     "`?

Comment: spaces at the beginning / end should not be allowed

Comment: I posted the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654495/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
Validators.pattern('\\s*\\S+(?: \\S+)*\\s*') // if at there can be 0 or more leading/trailing whitespaces
Validators.pattern('\\s?\\S+(?: \\S+)*\\s?') // if at there can be 1 or 0 leading/trailing whitespaces
```

Or, regex literal equivalent:

```
Validators.pattern(/^\s*\S+(?: \S+)*\s*$/) // if at there can be 0 or more leading/trailing whitespaces
Validators.pattern(/^\s?\S+(?: \S+)*\s?$/) // if at there can be 1 or 0  leading/trailing whitespaces
```

It will be parsed as

- `^` - start of string (implicit for a string pattern, it is added automatically)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?: \S+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a space followed with 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string (implicit for a string pattern, it is added automatically).

If you allow any whitespace between non-whitespace chunks, replace the literal space with `\s` (or `\\s`) in the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\s*([^\s]+\s?)*\s*` as your pattern.

This is: 0 or more spaces followed by zero or more (one or more non-space characters followed by up to one space) followed by 0 or more spaces.

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1cgzk

Comment: This `^\s*([^\s]+\s?)*\s*$` pattern is very bad. It will cause a time out with a very short non-matching text like [here](https://regex101.com/r/400vFj/1).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My original understanding of the question is that two+ spaces at the beginning should be allowed, but it seems like the updated question says they're not allowed at all which really changes things.